# What are the differences between "Olam" "Netzach" "Selah" "Va'ed" "Adey Ad"?

Tags: grammar-dikduk

What are the differences between "Olam" "Netzach" "Selah" "Va'ed" "Adey Ad"?

Comment: Closely related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10087 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28333 . See also [this article](https://ohr.edu/this_week/the_anatomy_of_a_mitzvah/7737), and the [Hebrew Wikipedia article](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%9C%D7%94_(%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%97_%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%99)).

Comment: No answer, just the way I think about this question. There are multiple kinds of "eternal" in Jewish thought: (1) will last as long as this world (ledoros = for the generations), (2) will last beyond olam haba -- infinite time, (3) is Beyond Time, Hashem's Eternity in that time isn't a relevent concept. And maybe until the end of history is shorter than until the end of olam hazeh, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

[*'Eruvin* 54a](https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.54a.14?lang=bi):

> תנא דבי רבי אליעזר בן יעקב כל מקום שנאמר נצח סלה ועד אין לו הפסק עולמית

Sefaria translation:

> A Sage of the school of Rabbi Eliezer ben Ya’akov taught the following baraita: Wherever it states netzaḥ, Selah, or va’ed, the matter will never cease. Netzaḥ, as it is written: “For I will not contend forever; neither will I be eternally [lanetzaḥ] angry” ([Isaiah 57:16](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1057.htm#16)), which demonstrates that netzaḥ bears a similar meaning to forever.

> Selah, as it is written: “As we have heard, so have we seen in the city of the Lord of Hosts, in the city of our God; may God establish it forever, Selah” ([Psalms 48:9](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2648.htm#9)), which demonstrates that Selah means forever. Va’ed, as it is written: “The Lord shall reign forever and ever [va’ed]” ([Exodus 15:18](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0215.htm#18)).

[Ibn 'Ezra (*T'hillim* 3:3)](https://www.sefaria.org/Ibn_Ezra_on_Psalms.3.3.4?lang=bi) brings various interpretations and concludes that *sela* serves to affirm that which was just stated, similar to *amein*:

> והנכון כי טעם סלה כמו כן הוא או ככה ואמת הדבר ונכון הוא

[Radak (ad loc.)](https://www.sefaria.org/Radak_on_Psalms.3.3.3?lang=bi) concludes that *sela* is a musical direction that indicates an accent (similar to [*sforzando*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamics_(music)#Sudden_changes_and_accented_notes)):

> ואני אומר כי איננה מלת ענין ופרושה לשון הגבהה מן סלו סלו המסלה (ישעיהו ס״ב:י׳) כלומר באותו המקום שהיא נזכרת ונקראת זאת המלה היתה הרמת קול המזמור